# Win32: List View Group Header Text Color

Tags: listview, winapi, textcolor

In Windows, a List View can have its items grouped, as in the following picture:

[image]

My application employs a white-on-black GUI. Most of the controls (buttons, edit fields, check-boxes etc.) I have created myself, but I am kind of fond of the Windows List View control, so I want to use it. To this end, I set the background colour to black and the text colour to white, to obtain

[image]

However, I cannot seem to find a way of changing the text colour of the group header. This is controlled by the theme, so it is by no means obvious that it even *can* be changed, but I am confident that you all see my need: The default blue color looks horrible on a black background.

So: Is there any means of chaning the text colour of a List View group header?

Comment: @Glorfindel: Thanks for fixing the links. However, it is enough to add the `s` to the `http` in the original links. Also, since I am a HTML semantics nerd, I don't quite like the use of the `sub` element to markup a source/footnote. From [the specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/textlevel-semantics.html#the-sub-and-sup-elements), "These elements must be used only to mark up typographical conventions with specific meanings, not for typographical presentation for presentation’s sake. [...] In general, authors should use these elements only if the absence of those elements would change the meaning

Comment: Thanks, if you want I can make an exception for your site in the script. I can even send you a list with affected posts if you want to fix them yourself. In any case, this saves you some bandwidth...

Comment: Are there any other options for the attribution which would work semantically? Stack Exchange supports only a very specific subset of HTML.

Comment: @Glorfindel: Thanks. I just started going through my posts fixing HTTP links. It's manageable to do it manually. Yeah, I know the Markdown puts quite some restrictions on the markup and that SUB often is used for things like footnotes (despite it being against the intension in the HTML5 specs). I don't know of any other way to achieve the smaller font size (for *visual* output -- you also need to think about other UAs such as screen readers, search engines, etc.), unless you can use style="" (haven't tried it). Ideally, a class would be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running on XP, you can set the group header color through the `LVGROUPMETRICS` structure. But from your screen shots, you are obviously on Vista or later. Unfortunately, after XP, this message does nothing.

So, sorry, no, there is nothing you can do to change the color. You can't even owner draw them.

Comment: Yes, I know. It is highly annoying. All items can be owner-drawn, but not the headers...

Comment: Interestingly, Windows Explorer (on Windows 11) shows a flat-styled header line and arrow, which is additionally left-aligned instead of right-aligned.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to customize the entire list view group header using a custom drawn list view.

As an example, I include an outline of a method that handles the entire `CDDS_PREPAINT` drawing phase. It comes from an MFC based project, but I suppose it can be easily translated into a plain Win32 project or into other frameworks.

```cpp
void CMyServiceList::OnCustomDraw(NMHDR* nmhdr, LRESULT* result)
{
    auto nmlvcd = LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW(nmhdr);

    switch (nmlvcd->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
    {
    case CDDS_PREPAINT:
    {
        switch (nmlvcd->dwItemType)
        {
        case LVCDI_GROUP:
        {
            const int nGroupId = int(nmlvcd->nmcd.dwItemSpec);

            wchar_t strGroupName[256] = L"";
            wchar_t strSubTitle[256] = L"";
            LVGROUP lvg = {
                .cbSize = sizeof(LVGROUP),
                .mask = LVGF_HEADER | LVGF_STATE | (!nGroupId ? LVGF_SUBTITLE : 0u),
                .pszHeader = strGroupName,
                .cchHeader = _countof(strGroupName),
                .stateMask = 0xff,
                .pszSubtitle = strSubTitle,
                .cchSubtitle = _countof(strSubTitle),
            };
            auto b = GetGroupInfo(nGroupId, &lvg);

            // Drawing code of entire group header
            // ...

            *result = CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT;
        }
        return;
        break;
        }
    }
        break;
    }

    CListCtrl::OnCustomDraw(nmhdr, result);
}
```